# invalid conversion from ‘mpfr_srcptr’ error compiling CGAL program in Debian

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to compile this CGAL program:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> Delaunay;

typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef std::vector<Point_2> Points;

int main()
{
    Points points;
    points.push_back(Point_2(0,0));
    points.push_back(Point_2(0,7));
    points.push_back(Point_2(7,0));
    points.push_back(Point_2(7,7));

    Delaunay dt(points.begin(), points.end());

    // Print Cartesian coordinates of vertices of triangles in 2D Delaunay triangulation
    for (Delaunay::Finite_faces_iterator it = dt.finite_faces_begin(); it != dt.finite_faces_end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << " " << dt.triangle(it)[0].x() << " " << dt.triangle(it)[0].y() << " ";
        std::cout << " " << dt.triangle(it)[1].x() << " " << dt.triangle(it)[1].y() << " ";
        std::cout << " " << dt.triangle(it)[2].x() << " " << dt.triangle(it)[2].y() << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl << "-------------------" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running Debian Sid and I have installed from the official repositories the packages libcgal-dev 5.5.1-2 and libmpfr-dev 4.1.1-1 plus their dependencies. But I obtain this error at compiling time:

```
$ g++ -Wall test_cgal.cc -o test_cgal -lcgal
In file included from /usr/include/CGAL/boost_mp.h:54,
                 from /usr/include/CGAL/Number_types/internal/Exact_type_selector.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/CGAL/Exact_kernel_selector.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/CGAL/Filtered_kernel.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h:21,
                 from hola.cc:1:
/usr/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpfr_type.h: In constructor ‘CGAL::Gmpfr::Gmpfr(mpfr_srcptr)’:
/usr/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpfr_type.h:199:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘mpfr_srcptr’ {aka ‘const __mpfr_struct*’} to ‘mpfr_ptr’ {aka ‘__mpfr_struct*’} [-fpermissive]
  199 |                         mpfr_custom_get_kind(f),
      |                         ^
      |                         |
      |                         mpfr_srcptr {aka const __mpfr_struct*}
/usr/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpfr_type.h: In constructor ‘CGAL::Gmpfr::Gmpfr(mpfr_srcptr, std::float_round_style, Precision_type)’:
/usr/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpfr_type.h:216:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘mpfr_srcptr’ {aka ‘const __mpfr_struct*’} to ‘mpfr_ptr’ {aka ‘__mpfr_struct*’} [-fpermissive]
  216 |                                 mpfr_custom_get_kind(f),
      |                                 ^
      |                                 |
      |                                 mpfr_srcptr {aka const __mpfr_struct*}
/usr/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpfr_type.h: In constructor ‘CGAL::Gmpfr::Gmpfr(mpfr_srcptr, Precision_type)’:
/usr/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpfr_type.h:237:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘mpfr_srcptr’ {aka ‘const __mpfr_struct*’} to ‘mpfr_ptr’ {aka ‘__mpfr_struct*’} [-fpermissive]
  237 |                                 mpfr_custom_get_kind(f),
      |                                 ^
      |                                 |
      |                                 mpfr_srcptr {aka const __mpfr_struct*}
```

Why the error `invalid conversion from ‘mpfr_srcptr’ {aka ‘const __mpfr_struct*’} to ‘mpfr_ptr’ {aka ‘__mpfr_struct*’}`? The MPFR version is the same from Debian stable to Debian Sid

Comment: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/7064

Comment: @MarcGlisse Are you sure it is the same issue? I don't see *"invalid conversion"* in the Github issue. And I have the same problem than the OP on Windows: [temporary link](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-devel-windows-x86_64/cgalMeshes-00install.html).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent If you do not have the latest version of MPFR, please upgrade it first. For messages, "cannot convert A to B" and "cannot construct B from A" seem like a normal variation from one (version of a) compiler to another.

Comment: @MarcGlisse This program is not linked to MPFR but however there's still this error: https://win-builder.r-project.org/08In5yEfjmir/00install.out Unless the linking to MPFR is automatic ? I didn't set `-lmpfr` to compile.

Comment: jgpallero> Have you been able to solve this issue finally?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that's a "compile" error, it happens before the linker is even invoked. And yes, CGAL uses MPFR by default unless you explicitly disable it. I don't understand what's preventing you from upgrading MPFR...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Because this is the report for a R package I submit to CRAN. I told them they should upgrade MPFR but they didn't reply. Thanks.